# Google Inbox as a standalone app via Chrome

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, plist, chrome-extensions

Google Inbox recently added compatibility with Safari and yet still does not play nice with Fluid.

I decided I might as well use Chrome. Google recently improved the way "desktop app extensions" work by giving them their own independent icons in Applications and Launchpad.

Unfortunately, this is acting like a glorified bookmark, rather than a standalone app. I.e., it opens with a toolbar and opens the site as a tab. I tried exploring the "contents" of the application icon Google creates. I found a plist but could not figure out if there was away to force the app to open an independent standalone Chrome window.

Any ideas on how I could modify the app to act less like a bookmark and more like a standalone desktop app ?

Comment: I know that Chrome apps depend on Google Chrome to be running but you say that they opens in a new tab, like a webpage. When I open a Google Chrome app, for example Chrome Remote Desktop, it opens in a new window and behaves more like an application, but I requires Google Chrome to run in the background.

Comment: That is a native desktop app. They do function like you say, the pocket app for example. But then they also have these desktop website apps without that capability. inbox for example.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to convert those apps to act like a desktop application. I think they are more like links. In those apps that opens like a tab, is there any offline data or are they relying on web content for everything?

Answer (score 1):

[Akmal has released Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/app-launcher-for-inbox-by/ajjmenfgmbpceneffopmikhahnkeebje?hl=en) that does exactly this.
You could take a look at his code to see how he's done it.

I would mention that he is running the webview through scan.me, so getting analytics to how many people are visiting it.

Answer (score -1):

[This script will create an app from a website for you](https://www.lessannoyingcrm.com/blog/2010/08/149/Create+application+shortcuts+in+Google+Chrome+on+a+Mac).

There is either an instalator or a shell script to enter the name, icon and url for your app to be shown in your default browser without toolbars. It opens in a separate profile user profile so you will have to login again  there. If you need an extensions for that profile you need to add them in a new tab which opens in a new window.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the free wrappers [WMail](http://lifehacker.com/wmail-is-a-free-os-x-desktop-app-for-inbox-by-gmail-1753207088) or [gInbox](https://github.com/chenasraf/gInbox).